# TYPO3 Escape Fluid ViewHelper object properties

Tags: typo3, fluid

I get back from a ViewHelper an object domain model 'post' in Fluid, by calling:

`{p:lastPost(topic: topic)}` or `<p:lastPost topic="{topic}"/>`

How do I access the properties in Fluid with this syntax?

Like name would normally be `{lastPost.author.name}`

And date 
`{lastPost.crdate -> f:format.date(format: '%d %B %Y')}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution found with f:alias

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Alias.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are on TYPO3 >= Version 8 you can use the `f:variable` Viewhelper. `f:alias` works too, but is not as comfortable to use.
For the variable ViewHelper you can use this syntax:

```
<f:variable name="myPostObject" value="{p:lastPost(topic: topic)}" />
{myPostObject.anyMemberVar}
```